# Android onLocationUpdate not called with GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps

Hi
I have an Android service using the location manager :

`if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

Log.i("service","start with GPS");    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,     0,locationListener);

}`

Then the location listener :

`private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

public void onLocationChanged(Location aLocation) {

Log.i("location listener", "location updated");

}

... other methods ....

}`

In the manifest, the authorization for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is set.

Everything works ok both in simulator and phone ( Xperia Android 1.6 to 2.2 ) for NETWORK_PROVIDER. It works fine in simulator for GPS_PROVIDER. But when I try to use the GPS in the devices, the location listener is never called. I can see in the DDMS that the GPS is actually working and retrieve locations, but it never calls the listener methods.
There is a strange message though :

WARN/libloc_api(1173): loc_eng_report_position: ignore position report when session status = 1

I can not see what I am missing. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: How long do you wait for position fix ? Is the GPS icon animating or still?

Comment: Well, I wait for a minute or 2, but in the log in DDMS, I see that the GPS is finding positions, as it reports lat/lng. How long is it suppose to take ?

Comment: 1 to 15 minutes. Once it gets a fix, the icon will stop animating in the status bar.

Comment: Duh ... It finally happened after 20 mn ... Ok, solution was : wait long enough ... If you wish put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes a while to get a location fix. The time to first fix de(TTFF) depends on a lot of factors, like number of visible GPS satellites, signal to noise ratio, the GPS chipset etc ...

Here is [a nice article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) that will help you get the best out of GPS on android phones.